# Tallyboard for Clean Up

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Should there be added to the Leaderboard a Total for all the clean up efforts?

```
Total questions cleaned: = 
Dupes: =
New Answers: =
Voting: =
Closes: =
```

Maybe include a header on the main page

Comment: What is the leader board, and how does one get involved in helping to cleanup?

Comment: Good question -- Go here:  http://cleanup.thepcspy.com/leaderboard/ and discover what its all about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since March of 2012 no new activity. Gonna answer this with (not going to happen)

Comment: Eh, I've used the clean-up script in both April and May... Maybe I'm not understanding?

Comment: Back a year ago when the script was first introduced and we had a challenge. I suggested a tally-board. Must have been before your time cleaning up. This question is outdated now.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.